# New approch for selectionsort in java

Tags: java, sorting

```
package com;

public class SimpleSelectionSort {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array={1,2,0,0,3,4,7,5,4,8,77,665,55,44,445,6};
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        int min= i;
        if(i>0&&array[min]==array[min-1])
            continue;
        for(int j=i+1;j<array.length;j++){
            if(i>0&&array[j]==array[i-1]){
                min=j;
                break;
            }
            if(array[j]<array[min])min=j;
            }
         swap(array,i,min);  
    }
    show(array);
}
private static void swap(int[] array,int i,int min){
    int value=array[i];
    array[i]=array[min];
    array[min]=value;
}

private static void show(int[] a){
    for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++){
    System.out.println(a[j]);
    }
}

}
```

Plz review the code and let me .know is this is a better way of selection sorting I eliminated time taken for sorting repeated values

Comment: Maybe try codereview.stackexchange.

Comment: And please write in complete sentences - don't use "plz"!

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is still O(n^2), so it does not change. If you wanna a faster sort - I would look into merge or quick sort O(n*log n). Or some O(n) sorts depending on the situation.

What's your goal in here? Per say you don't have any duplicates in your array -will your sort be faster then? Are you trying to improve selection sort with lots of duplicates? What's your array's span range? Maybe it's wiser to use Bucket sort?